# Cannot ping other server from Execute Shell in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to run a Jenkins job in a Mac using "Execute Shell" on it.
The problem is that I need to perform a network call, for example doing a `ping google.com`, but i'm getting an error:

```
ping google.com

ping: cannot resolve google.com: Unknown host
```

I tried injecting environment variables but it didn't worked.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it running Jenkins with DNSMultiCast disabled, apparently it's enabled by default.

```
java -Dhudson.DNSMultiCast.disabled=true -jar jenkins.war
```